# Get page content from Apache Commons HTTP Request

Tags: java, http, apache-commons

So I'm using Apache Commons HTTP to make a request to a webpage.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the actual content from the page, I can just get its header information.  How can I get the actual content from it?

Here is my example code:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://URL_HERE/");

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

System.out.println("Response: " + response.toString());
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`HttpResponse#getEntity()`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html#getEntity%28%29) and then [`HttpEntity#getContent()`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContent%28%29) to obtain it as an `InputStream`.

```
InputStream input = response.getEntity().getContent();
// Read it the usual way.
```

Note that [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) isn't part of [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org). It's part of [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/).

Answer (score 17):

BalusC's comment will work just fine.
If you're using version 4 or newer of Apache HttpComponents, there is a convenience method you can use as well:
`EntityUtils.toString(HttpEntity);`

Here's what it'll look like in your code:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://URL_HERE/");
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String entityContents = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Not sure if this is due to different versions, but I had to rewrite it like this:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://URL_HERE/");
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String entityContents = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
response.getEntity();
```

You really want to look at the Javadocs, the example for HttpClient shows you how to get at all the info in the response: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the content of the URL, you can use the URL API, like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class URLTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com.br");
        //here you have the input stream, so you can do whatever you want with it!
        Scanner in = new Scanner(url.openStream());
        in.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would have just used this but I needed to use Apache Commons because this is in conjunction with more stuff.